How to access a model's compiled Configuration (optimizer, losses, etc.) without loading with compile=True in TensorFlow/Keras?
I'm trying to load a previously saved model and access its compiled configuration (e.g., optimizer, loss functions) without re-compiling the model. Typically, I would use compile=True while loading the model to access these details, like this:
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model, compile=True)

optimizer = loaded_model.optimizer
loss_fns = loaded_model.compiled_loss._user_losses
loss_weights = loaded_model.compiled_loss._user_loss_weights

However, I need to load the model without compiling it (compile=False), but I still need to access the optimizer and loss functions. Is there any way to retrieve these details after loading the model without using compile=True?
# Load the model without compiling
loaded_model = tf.keras.models.load_model(model, compile=False)

Any advice on how to access this configuration would be appreciated! Thanks

To my knowledge, with compile=False, I would say that it doesn't seem possible but you could save the info (like model.optimizer.get_config()) in a json file at the same time as you save the model in h5.

@rehaqds thank you for the suggestion. Indeed, that's the workaround I'm following.
